# Return two values back to Ajax from controller

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Is it possible to return false and a additional datatype(like int, bool etc) from controller back to Ajax?

```
 $.post('/Home/SomeAction', { "id": Id }, function (data) {
                if (data) {  
                     ...
                   }else if(data.anotherBool == true){
                   //....
                   }
```

I need three values for tree different purpose, true, false, and another boolean.

```
 public JsonResult SomeAction(int id) {

        ........

       return Json(false, anotherBoolean); //<-- what I want
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can do that by using `JSON`. Try something like this from your controller:

```
public JsonResult yourFunctionName()
{
      // your code here
      return Json(new {booleanValue = anotherBoolean, intValue = anotherIntValue}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Additionally, you can get the values in your Ajax call like this:

```
$.post('/Home/SomeAction', { "id": Id }, function (data) {
            if (data.intValue == 1) {  
               //....
            }
            else if(data.booleanValue == true){
               //....
            }
```

Comment: need to set `dataType` for `$.post`

Comment: @Senjuti Mahapatra ...please help me, i want to pass message in return so how it's possible? in mvc

Comment: @Brij - You can do something like this `return Json(new {booleanValue = anotherBoolean, intValue = anotherIntValue, message = "some string"}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);`

Answer (score 0):

```
public JsonResult FunctionName()
{
      // do your coding
var result=Json(new {param1 = val1 , param2 = val2});
      return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Get value in Json as:

```
var val1 = response.Data.param1;

var val2 = response.Data.param2;
```